# last login shell script

Tags: command-line, server, 18.04

So I used google to figure out that `last -1 -R -s yesterday -t today` gets me this:

[image: How can get just the date]

and from what I understand `awk -FS '{print $2}` should just get me this part of the `last` command when it's piped in

[image: this is what I need]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `cut` in combination of `tr`:

```
last -1 -R -s yesterday -t today | grep -vi reboot |  tr -s ' ' | cut -f 3-6 -d ' ' -s
```

```
Sat Jun 29 15:59
Fri Jun 29 06:45:15
...
```

- `tr -s ' '` to squeeze repeats, so we can easily cut by space as a separator.
- `grep` to exclude any reboot line.
- `cut` well to cut things :)

Comment: this is amazing but I only need the first line not both

Comment: @bckelley Try `last -1 -R | head -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 3-6`

Comment: @SamuelSantana No, I only want one date see above,

Comment: @bckelley Forgot `-s yesterday -t today`. But that should do what you want, `head -n 1 ` gets you only the first line. Then we use Ravexina's solution.

Comment: @SamuelSantana I had the `-s yesterday -t today` part forgot the `head -n 1` Thanks to you both @Ravenxina